# Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH endpoint details. while using FTP upload to remote server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to do a release on Azure Devops using the SFTP upload task to a hosting server of my own (not Azure related) but it keeps throwing the following error "Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH endpoint details." It's just a simple HTML file. Can anyone help me out on this?